# How to make simple html 5 Validation in Metro-Style?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm develoing Windows 8 metro style application with Html 5 and Javascript

My question is simple, how can write simple form with validation ?

```
<form id="loginForm">
        E-Mail:
        <input id="login-email" type="email" name="Username" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Enter email pls')" 
    maxlength="40" required pattern="^.{2,}@.{2,}$"/>

        Password:
        <input id="login-password" type="password" name="Password" maxlength="25" required pattern=".{6,10}"/>

    <button name="login" type="submit" class="go-login" id="btnlogin" value="LOGIN">LOGIN</button></form>
```

This is my html 5 form. But the problem is metro style event listener...

```
document.getElementById("btnlogin").addEventListener('click', loginClick);
```

When I click the submit button, the EventListener's "loginClick" function launches without checking html 5 form input elements valid or not.

Comment: Shouldn't you use onsubmit, not click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran into the same issue while working with HTML5/JS Windows Store Application (WSA).  The expectation is that the user is notified on the client and that the code in the 'Submit' does not run. This is what we see on a web-based HTML5 application running in the browser.  However, the WSA app runs the submit code when the button is clicked regardless of the validation status.  In my application, I included a check of the loginForm.checkValidity() property.  This is true when all validation is correct.

```
if (loginForm.checkValidity())
{
  //...submit logic...
}
```

I agree, this check is an extra step given our expectations from the web world.  This is still version 1 of the WSA platform and I expect this functionality will evolve into the product in a future update/release.

Answer (score 1):

According to w3schools, you have to call onsubmit="return function()" in the form tag.
This way it should not proceed to submit without going through the validation.

grabbed from W3schools:

```
<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post">
Email: <input type="text" name="email">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and the belonging javascript:

```
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
    {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
    return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, Html5 validation is working at the same time with eventlistener's function. I think, I should call a validation function in eventListener's "loginClick" function. But this is not the perfect way. It's not best practice.